# How to integrate Aloha Editor in Asp.net MVC and Submit to Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aloha-editor

I have included js files and able to see the control on the browser.

Could you please anybody explain how to use Aloha editor in Asp.net MVC framework, I strucked at getting the value from Editor control and post to data base.

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how to save content from aloha editor using .Net MVC.

This should be enough to get you started.

Add a button to save the content on the same page as Aloha editor

```
<input type="button" id="save-content" value="save"/>
```

Create a controller action to save your content.

```
public ActionResult SaveContent(string editor, string content)
{
    //save content to db here
    return Json(new {success = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then add the following script to the page.
This will loop through any aloha editors on your page, and make an ajax request to save the content using the controller action you just created.

```
<script>   
    $('#save-content').on('click', function() {

        jQuery.each(Aloha.editables, function(index, editable) {
            $.ajax({
                url: @Url.Action("SaveContent"),
                type: 'post',
                data: {editor: editable.getId(), content: editable.getContents()}
            }).done(function(){
                alert('content saved');
            });    
        });
    });
</script>
```